# Make $DEFINE permanent across several modules

Tags: delphi

I have some several projects that use some common code. There are conditional defines in the project settings and I'd like to be able to define some symbols that persist across several modules. For example:

```
{$IF Defined(PROJ1_DEBUG) or Defined(PROJ1_NDEBUG)}
    {$DEFINE PROJ1}     // Project 1
{$ELSEIF Defined(PROJ2_DEBUG) or Defined(PROJ2_NDEBUG)}
    {$DEFINE PROJ2}     // Project 2
{$ELSEIF Defined(PROJ3_DEBUG) or Defined(PROJ3_NDEBUG)}
    {$DEFINE PROJ3}     // Project 3
{$IFEND}
```

That could appear at the top of the main project file, say. Now I'd like to be able to use the following conditional compilation in several units across the projects:

```
{$IFDEF PROJ1}
// Do something specific to project 1
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF PROJ2}
// Do something specific to project 2
{$ENDIF}
```

but I'm finding that "PROJ1" and "PROJ2" (and "PROJ3", of course) are not defined when I try and use them. The Embarcadero help (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/DEFINE_directive_(Delphi)) suggests my symbols will only be defined for the current module, but doesn't offer any assistance on defining them across multiple modules.

Is it possible to define more permanent symbols so I can define them once and then use them across multiple modules?

Comment: What's your definition of a "Module"? I'm assuming you mean Projects.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Same as Embarcadero's. See the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Define the conditional at the project level. Do this from the project options dialog.
2. Define the conditional in an include file that you include in every unit that needs to test the conditional.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:
{$IF Defined(PROJ1_DEBUG) or Defined(PROJ1_NDEBUG)}
 {$I Proj1Options.inc}  // Project 1
{$ELSEIF Defined(PROJ2_DEBUG) or Defined(PROJ2_NDEBUG)}
 {$I Proj2Options.inc}  // Project 2
{$ELSEIF Defined(PROJ3_DEBUG) or Defined(PROJ3_NDEBUG)}
 {$I Proj3Options.inc}  // Project 3
{$IFEND}
Is there no other way to define the symbol across multiple modules?

Comment: I would imagine that you'd move the `$IF` and its else clauses into an include file. *Is there no other way to define the symbol across multiple modules?* You have the two options presented in my answer.

Comment: OK, tried it with a conditional include (.inc) file for each project type. In the .inc file for each project I then conditionally define the symbols I need. Works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some modification to [David Heffernan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29079654/3578861) answer.

I have several project with common code base too.

I make the subfolder `include` in code folder, and several subfolders named `project1`..`projectN`. Each of them contain `directives.inc` file with something like:

```
{$define Some_project_condition1}
```

In project's code, where I need a special behaviour, I put

```
{$include directives.inc}
{$ifdef Some_project_condition1}
    // some special code
{$else}
    {$message error 'DO NOT FORGET ABOUT IT!!!'}
{$endif}
```

And, of couse, I put the relative path to `include\projectN\directives.inc` subfolder to each project `Search path`.

I prefer this variant instead project condition defines because I can put const's and var's to `.inc` file too.